# Private API to embed a Mac Catalyst component in a native AppKit app?

Tags: swift, objective-c, appkit, mac-catalyst, iphone-privateapi

I would like to embed a Mac Catalyst component, like TOCropViewController or MessageKit (I am not providing a link to either to avoid getting this post flagged as spam, but if you google them you will find that they handle a lot of functionality that cannot be easily replicated), in a native AppKit app.

I do not distribute my app in the App Store, so I am OK with private APIs.

**To be clear: I do not want do add an AppKit component to a Mac Catalyst app; I want to do the reverse, as I already have a very large AppKit codebase**

Comment: Is there a [mac-privateapi] tag (or equivalent)? I couldn’t find it if there is; sorry.

Comment: FYI - there is nothing wrong with providing links to relevant documentation in a question. That will not trigger any SPAM flags.